# Magento2 : Facing proble with call custom jquery function in Backend

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, requirejs

I have to call custom jquery function into Magento backend (sales > Order > View)

[image]

I have created custom js in adminhtml/web/js/order_status_validation.js

```
require(['jquery'], function(jQuery){
jQuery(function(){

    function do_validation_history() {
        alert('Coming');
        return false;
    }

  });
});
```

While we can click on submit button we are getting an error like

```
 ReferenceError: do_validation_history is not defined
```

I have called custom js into `sales_order_view.xml`

Can anyone know how we can resolve this error?

Comment: are you sure order_status_validation.js is coming on the page.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working fine with blow code

```
require([
'jquery',
 ], function(jQuery){

historyValidate = {
    validation: function(url) {
        console.log('this is test');
        return false; 
    }
}
jQuery(function ($) {
    console.log('this is test');
  });
 });

now adding historyValidate.validation(event); where my function call.
```

Answer (score 1):

Below I am sharing the way I use for any jquery in magento 2.
Let me know if you feel any difficulty to understand.

```
require(['jquery'], function(jQuery){

    var do_validation = {
        history: function (event){
            alert('Coming');
            return false;
        }
    }

    window.do_validation = do_validation;
});
```

Now you can use **`do_validation.history(event);`** from any where on the page.

You can also use below function outside of require js and call the function outside on the same page

```
function do_validation_history() {
        alert('Coming');
        return false;
    }
```